# fullCalendar.js Multi-Day Events with Weekends hidden

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

The problem: I have a multi-date event beginning on a Sunday and ending during the week. Toggle the `weekends` setting for the calendar and notice that this event now drops out of the view (even though it *does* span into the weekdays). See attached screengrabs.

Am I going to have to parse incoming events from the server, see if the current view has weekends off and if they do, and if I have an event beginning on a weekend day, force it's `start` value to that Monday in order to get it to show?

Weekends On, multi-date event spans correctly

[image]

Weekends Off, event is gone

[image]

I am using the settings as described in the documentation. Everything has worked as expected except for this.

Comment: 1) Please state your version of fullcalendar. 2) Please provide a [mre] of the issue including your calendar setup code and sample event data in JSON format, so that we can test it, reproduce it, and then attempt a diagnosis and fix (or we will refer to you the [fullCalendar issues page](https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs), if we rule out an issue in your code so that it looks like an internal FullCalendar bug). We cannot fix pictures alone. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your post. Thankyou